# Getting undefined method in my before_filter clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined, before-filter

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to define a filter subject to certain conditions.  So I have

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :store_last_page_visited unless logged_in?

…

  private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def store_last_page_visited
    session[:last_page_visited] = request.url
  end

  helper_method :current_user, :logged_in?
```

However, when I visit a page in my application, I get the error

```
undefined method `logged_in?' for ApplicationController:Class Did you mean? logger
```

What do I need to do differently to get my filter executed when I specify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`before_filter` is executed in the context of the class.

`#logged_in?` is defined in the context of the class instance.

Try this:

```
def store_last_page_visited
  return if logged_in?

  session[:last_page_visited] = request.url
end
```